# How to setup multiple tracking levels of branchs with git

Tags: git, git-remote, smartgit

I have a git local branch that tracked the remote svn trunk.

I created a new development branch and set the local branch to track it.

I want that the development branch will also track the svn/trunk
something like:

```
from:
local branch > development branch

to:
local branch > development branch > svn/trunk
```

Is it possible to do it with git?

I'm using
git version 2.14.3

git GUI - smartgit v18.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible in Git.  But it's also not that important (really!), because *tracking a branch* in Git just means that the one branch has the other set as its *upstream:*

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=desired-upstream my-branch
```

Each of your branches can have *at most one* upstream at any time.  When your branch *does* have an upstream, the following occur:

- `git fetch` with no arguments knows which other Git repository may contain commits to be fetched.  Hence you can run `git fetch` instead of `git fetch remote`.

  But if you only have one remote named `origin`, as is pretty common, this doesn't really buy you anything since `git fetch` with no arguments will fetch from `origin` if it has nothing better from an upstream.  In other words, `git fetch` already fetches from the (single) correct remote anyway.  So having an upstream here did not buy you anything.
- `git merge` and `git rebase` run with no additional arguments automatically know which remote-tracking name to use.  This *does* buy you something, but if you'd like to have two upstreams, you would still have had to tell `git merge` or `git rebase` *which upstream* to use, so having to type `git merge fred/xyzzy` and `git merge giselle/xyzzy` isn't really much worse.  In fact it's probably better: `git merge upstream1` and `git merge upstream2` are shorter to type, but is `fred/xyzzy` upstream #1, or is it upstream #2?  Why not use the more memorable name?
- Like the other two above, `git pull`—which just *runs* the other two, fetch first and then one of the other two commands—also knows what to use by default.  I recommend that most Git users *avoid* `git pull` as it's meant to be a convenience command, but tends to be inconvenient at the worst times.  If you avoid `git pull`, having it know things buys you nothing at all.
- The default `git push` behavior, using the standard `push.default` setting of `simple`, is better.  This *does* buy you something, but you probably should only be pushing to one other Git repository anyway, so you can pick that particular other Git repository as the (single) upstream for the branch.
- Last, the `git status` command (which some other Git commands run, or run part of) becomes more informative, telling you how many commits you are ahead of and behind the chosen upstream.  This includes `git branch -v` as well.  I find this has significant value.

Fortunately, there's a simple way to get the same information from the command line, and you can make an alias or script to do this for you.  When `git status` says that you're "ahead 1" and/or "behind 3", it's running the equivalent of:

```
git rev-list --count --left-right <local-name>...<upstream-name>
```

For instance, with branch `stash-exp` having `origin/master` as its upstream, I can run:

```
git rev-list --count --left-right stash-exp...origin/master
```

and get the same two numbers (as raw numbers): the first is the "ahead" count and the second is the "behind" count.  Note the *three* periods `.` here; this form of this command and options requires all three, while most commands mostly use the two-dot syntax instead.

In summary, then, setting an upstream, so that some local branch name tracks either some remote-tracking name, or some other local branch name, has a very low cost (one command) and some noticeable benefits, so you should do it when it makes sense.  But the benefits are not so huge as to *need* to have more than one upstream.

Comment: thanks for the answer, so as I understand branches can have at most one upstream at any time.
so is it possible to set a remote branch to track another remote branch? or it's only possible for a local branch?

Comment: It's only available for local branches. A remote-tracking name, like `origin/master`, is *automatically changed* to match `master` on `origin` every time your Git calls up the Git at `origin` and inspects its `master`. So it makes no sense to set an upstream for that—but on the *other* Git, where it's a *local* branch (`master`), you can set an upstream there!