# How to clone, then sync/update/push a fork with the upstream master

Tags: git, github, git-clone, git-checkout, git-fetch

I think I've read through some of the tutorials and I'm stuck on something entirely basic (I hardly ever use the commandline git, so please be patient ;)).

All I want to do is update my fork (https://github.com/abelbraaksma/visualfsharp) to the latest version of Master (https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp) from the upstream repo. Since I have local changes that I do not care about, I decided to create a new clone (previously I used GUI tools, but they are so confusing and limiting that I gave up on that and dived into the woods of git commands ;).

I did:

```
cd /D/Projects/OpenSource/VisualFSharp2
git init
git clone https://github.com/abelbraaksma/visualfsharp
git fetch https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp
git remote add upstream https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp
git remote add origin https://github.com/abelbraaksma/visualfsharp
git fetch upstream
git checkout master
git merge upstream/master
```

That last two commands give:

> `git checkout master`
>   Already on 'master'
>   Your branch is up to date with 'upstream/master'.
>
> `git merge upstream/master`
>   Already up to date.

I realize I did some things in the wrong order and since I come from SVN and Mercurial worlds, I am often confused by terminology.

I understand that currently I am in "master" of the upstream repo. But I need to merge from the upstream repo into the origin (my fork) repo. I assume I need to update the local copy to whatever the head is of my fork (but `git checkout master` doesn't do that).

I basically tried to follow [this guide on syncing](https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/), combined with [configuring remote points](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-remote-for-a-fork/).

Where am I confused or better, what commands did I get backward?

Doing `git remote -v` gives me:

> ```
> origin  https://github.com/abelbraaksma/visualfsharp (fetch)  
> origin  https://github.com/abelbraaksma/visualfsharp (push)  
> upstream        https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp (fetch)  
> upstream        https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp (push)
> ```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### TL;DR

You're OK, but you have an extra repository you probably should just delete.  You should generally start by cloning (with `git clone`) the repository that you want to have your Git call `origin`, and then `git remote add upstream <the other url>` and work from there.

Read the long description below to see what you have now and how to work with it.

#### Long: what you did, in detail

> ```
> git init
> ```

This creates a new, empty Git repository in the current directory.  (If there is already a Git repository here—if `git rev-parse --git-dir` would print some directory name, rather than failing and saying "I find no repository"—it basically does nothing at all, making it safe to run.  There are some corner cases here but you are unlikely to run into them.)  Since you intend to clone a repository, you don't really want to this, because `git clone` *also* does a `git init`, as we will see in a moment.

Before we go on to the `git clone` below, let's take a moment to make a note about a weird state for a new, empty repository.  You are probably familiar by now with the idea that a *branch name* like `master` actually just holds the hash ID of one (1) commit.  Git uses the name to find the *last* commit on the branch, which Git calls the *tip commit*.  Git then uses the tip commit to find the previous or *parent* commit, and uses the parent's parent to work back through history.  By following the chain of parents, Git finds all the commits that are *reachable* from the branch name.

But an empty repository *has no commits*.  There's no tip of `master` for the name `master` to point-to—no latest commit in `master` whose hash ID can be stored under the name `master`.  Git's solution is to not *have* a `master` branch yet.  At the same time, Git declares that you are "on branch master", as `git status` would say—so you're *on a branch that doesn't exist yet*.

This weirdness factors in later.  For now, let's move on to `git clone`, and look at what it does.  In this case it makes another, separate repository, which you subsequently don't use at all.

> ```
> git clone https://github.com/abelbraaksma/visualfsharp
> ```

This is mostly equivalent to the series of commands:

- `mkdir visualfsharp`: create a new sub-directory within the current directory (current being `/D/Projects/OpenSource/VisualFSharp2`)
- `cd visualfsharp`: enter the new sub-directory
- `git remote add origin https://github.com/abelbraaksma/visualfsharp`: add the remote named `origin` (this configures a few settings for it as well)
- `git fetch origin`: obtain all their commits
- `git checkout somebranch`, where *`somebranch`* is usually `master`: creates a local branch name from one of the `origin/*` names and makes that the current branch.

When these are done you are back in your original directory (i.e., still `/D/Projects/OpenSource/VisualFSharp2`).  Note that your original directory is one Git repository, and its `visualfsharp` subdirectory is another.

We're going to see you do most of these commands again now, but this time, applied to your currently-empty repository, which is in that weird state where you're on `master` but `master` does not exist.

> ```
> git fetch https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp
> ```

This calls up the Git at `https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp` and obtains commits and other objects from them, into your previously empty repository (not the clone you just made!).  It's like `git fetch remote` except that there are no remote-tracking names—no `origin/*` or `upstream/*`—since there's no remote to use to construct such names.  This particular form of `git fetch` dates back to ancient times (2005), before the invention of `git remote`, and one probably should never use it.  It's not *harmful*, it's just not *helpful* either here.

> ```
> git remote add upstream https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp
> git remote add origin https://github.com/abelbraaksma/visualfsharp
> ```

These are fine: they set up two *remotes*.  A remote is just a short name that:

- saves a URL, and
- provides the leading part of the remote-tracking names, `upstream/*` and `origin/*` respectively.

> ```
> git fetch upstream
> ```

This is *almost* a repeat of your earlier `git fetch`.  This time, though, your Git uses the name you assigned—`upstream`—to get the URL.  So your Git calls up the Git at `https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp` again.  Your Git gets from them any new commits (and any other necessary Git objects to go with those commits) since the last fetch—probably none, depending on just how long you went between the first fetch and this second one.  If you had not run the earlier `git fetch`, this would get every Git object while getting all the commits.

But now, having gotten the commits, there's a critical difference: your Git takes *all of their branch names* and renames them to your remote-tracking names spelled `upstream/whatever`.  It can do this now because now you're using a remote, not just a raw URL.  The remote—the literal string `upstream`—gets you this renaming.<sup>1</sup>  So your Git and their Git very quickly transfer all of the new objects (probably none), and then your Git sets up your `upstream/master` and so on, based on their `master` and so on.

> ```
> git checkout master
> ```

This is where the repository's weird state comes in.  Your Git will say:

```
Branch master set up to track remote branch master from upstream.
Already on 'master'
```

What happened is that `git checkout` looked for `master` and *did not find it* (because you have no branches), so it *created* one.  First it looked through all your remote-tracking names, `upstream/*` in this case.  It found one that matched: `master` vs `upstream/master`.  So it created your `master`, pointing to the same commit as your `upstream/master`.  It then also set up your `master` to have `upstream/master` as its *upstream* setting.

After doing all that—creating your `master`—`git checkout` tried to put you onto your `master`, and found that you were only on your `master` and printed that confusing "already on" message.  Still, it attached your HEAD properly in the process, checking out all the files, i.e., copying them to the index and to the work-tree.

You may or may not want your `master` set up this way—you are more likely to want your `master` to start out pointing to the same commit as your `origin/master`, once you create an `origin/master`, and to have `origin/master` set as its upstream.  For more about what an upstream is—i.e., what it means to have one branch set to *track*<sup>2</sup> another branch—see, e.g., [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51011214/1256452) to [How to setup multiple tracking levels of branchs with git](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51009710/1256452).

Your last command here was:

> ```
> git merge upstream/master
> ```

Your own `master` was just created *from* your `upstream/master`, so there is nothing to merge: the two names both point to the same commit hash ID.

You have yet to fetch anything from your `origin`.  You probably should do that now:

```
git fetch origin
```

Once you do, you will have `origin/master` as well as `upstream/master`.<sup>3</sup>  If you wish, as I suspect, to have your own `master` track `origin/master` rather than `upstream/master` (and to start from there), you should:

1. make sure there is nothing to commit (there should not be given the above sequence, but it's always wise to check before using `git reset --hard`);
2. run `git reset --hard origin/master` to make your `master` point to the same commit as `origin/master`; and
3. run `git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master master` to change the upstream setting.

*Now* you can run `git merge upstream/master`.  If the upstream has new commits since your own fork occurred, that will merge those commits, using either a full merge if required, or a fast-forward not-really-a-merge operation if possible.

In any case you probably want to delete the extra repository.

---

<sup>1</sup>The underlying mechanism by which Git achieves this renaming is horribly complicated, probably for historic reasons, but in normal practice it's just "change their `master` to your `remote/master`" and so on.

<sup>2</sup>Note that Git uses yet more confusing terminology here: if a a branch name *tracks* a *remote-tracking name* (which is a local name your Git creates based on a name found in another Git whose URL is found via a *remote*) then we call that the branch's (or branch name's) *upstream*.  This is all completely different from tracked vs untracked files.  Yikes!

<sup>3</sup>I am assuming here that the Git repository at `https://github.com/abelbraaksma/visualfsharp` is your own, and that you created it using GitHub's "fork a repository" clicky buttons in their Web GUI interface.  When you did that, GitHub did a somewhat complicated `git clone` on GitHub itself, creating your repository there from whatever source repository you chose.  That means that your GitHub repository has all the same branches as the original source repository.

(The clone GitHub makes does not rename branches.  It also has special GitHub-only features set up to allow the GitHub-provided pull request facility; this is not part of Git.  The GitHub folks also arrange to share underlying on-disk objects behind the scenes and have all kinds of other tricks to make this a lot faster than it would be if it were done naively.  So it's a regular clone *in principle*, but they have tweaked it to make it more useful via their web interface.  That's how they get you to use GitHub instead of just doing it all yourself. )

Comment: Thanks for this awesome answer! More than I could've ever wished for, altogether a nice tutorial from my "how not to do it" to your "how to do it and why".

Comment: _"Git uses yet more confusing terminology"_ >> amen to that! _"git fetch dates back to ancient times (2005) ... and one probably should never use it."_ >> yes, I thought it was synonymous to using the alias (remote), which now I understand is not quite the same, using the alias does add extra actions under the hood.

Comment: Great answer! But why do I have to setup upstream every time i clone my fork? Shouldn't git know already of which repo I made this fork?

Comment: @Sharak: no, Git has no way to know this. Git*Hub* know it, but they don't tell Git. `git clone`'s model has no place to put that information.

Answer (score 3):

I do something very similar to what you did, here's how I do it:

1. Get the fork's url.
2. Switch to terminal. `cd` to the directory where we want to clone.
3. `git clone fork-url-here` will clone our fork and set it as `remote/origin`.
4. `cd fork-name/` changing to the cloned directory.
5. `git remote add upstream upstream-url-here` will set the upstream as `remote/upstream`.
6. `git fetch upstream` fetches *all branches* from upstream.
7. `git checkout master` since we are already on origin/master we get a message informing us of the same. So, all is good and this is *not* indicative of an issue.
8. `git branch -a` lists all local + `remote/origin/*` + `remote/upstream/*` branches. One of these is going to be `upstream/master` (initially I used `git branch` which only shows the local branches, this confused me a bit as I could not see `upstream/master` in the list).
9. `git merge upstream/master` this will merge the `upstream/master` branch into your current branch, which is `origin/master`, thereby syncing to upstream.

The issue you face arose because just before you add the upstream as a remote, you fetch from it (fourth line in your code block). That will prevent you from fetching all the branches from upstream. Other things look fine to me.

P.S.: I can see that this is an old issue, but I just thought I might help git beginners (like me), who might be in a rush and cannot read the very nice and informative answer given by torek.

---

---

Edit/Extension 1: Another thing is to force the fork's (origin) master to be at the same level as the original repo's (upstream) master.

### !!!CAUTION: this WILL discard any and all commits made to your origin master!!!

If you are ABSOLUTELY SURE that you want to go through with it, then in the steps stated above, replace step 9 with the following:

- `git reset --hard upstream/master` will replace the content of origin/master (locally of course) by the content of upstream/master.
- `git push origin master --force` will forcefully push the changes you made to the remote origin.

I suggested this change because I recently had to do this myself, and found that this could help someone (only if they know what they are doing). But, since it also has the potential to destroy valuable work, I have repeatedly emphasized on the risk involved.

Comment: Thanks for the instructions. I've meanwhile gotten a little better in understanding the terminology and git commands, but this indeed may still help some others :)